# Windows installer log files showing a large group 2360 messages

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, custom-action, wix3

I am trying to run an installer using the MSI command line option so that I can run it in debug mode and see the logs.

The logs that I am getting are quite large (near to 1 MB) and they are full of the following messages:

```
MSI (s) (F8:5C) [16:26:27:385]: Note: 1: 2360
```

I want to know if this is something to worry about? I have looked up the error code 2360 at [Windows Installer Error Messages page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on msdn and all it says that

> Progress tick.

Is there something that I need to change in my installer?

I have recently added a CustomAction that makes use of System.Xml namespace. Could this be a cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with msi's for the first time and I see what you're talking about.

The reason you're getting "Note 1: 2360" is because the computer is writing. Writes take a long time which is why there's so many. Look at the 4 lines before the 2360. It'll be something like

```
Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=somename,...)
File: <filepath>filename;  To be installed;   won't patch;    No existing file
Source for file 'bunch of letters and numbers' is compressed
Note: 1: 2318 2: <filepath>filename
Note: 1: 2360
Note: 1: 2360
etc...
etc...
```

It tries to do a FileCopy of the existing file. Finds it doesn't exist. Identifies the source file. Throws error code 2318 of the new file because it doesn't exist yet (2318 means file does not exist). Then it starts writing and tells you its doing something by printing out "Note: 1: 2360".

If you ran the installer again I'm sure you'd find zero "Note: 1: 2360" anywhere in the log.

Comment: Old question, but this is still relevant to people starting out getting their hands dirty with msis and their logs. Like me.

Comment: Thanks and your answer provides much more information that I was able to find when I was working on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some information in the comments to article posted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*> Most times these "Note:" entires are just for information but sometimes they are precursors to other errors.*

posted by

Robert Flaming
Windows Installer Program Manager [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I hope the messages that I am getting are in fact just for information.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be because of Xml namespace. Please run this command in command prompt and provide the error details

```
msiexec /i "Path to msi" /l*v log.log
```

Once you get error, you can use **[WiLogUtl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** to read the log file. The tool is available with Windows SDK. Also the report will help you get exact error location

Comment: The msi install all right. The problem is that in the logs I get a large sequence of "MSI (s) (F8:5C) [16:26:27:385]: Note: 1: 2360" messages. This is from the log file. So these messages add up to make the log file size increase to 1MB. I want to know if this is something to worry about? Besides there are no other obvious errors in the logs file.

Comment: Yes the log file size will be pretty big as /l*v will log everything that installer does. There are different options for log available. You can try those